# How to catch io.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutException

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-webclient, reactor-netty

I am new to WebClient. I would like to handle a `io.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutException` thrown from the underlying HTTP client.

This is how I have configured my `HttpClient`, the one I am passing to `WebClient`.

```
HttpClient httpClient(){
    return HttpClient.create()
            .option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, 30000)
            .doOnConnected(connection -> {
                connection
                        .addHandlerLast(new WriteTimeoutHandler(30))
                        .addHandlerLast(new ReadTimeoutHandler(30));
            });
```

And here is my `WebClient` configuration.

```
@Bean
WebClient  webClient(){
    return WebClient.builder()
            .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient))
            .baseUrl("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com")
            .build();
}
```

And my code to perform the GET is below:

```
public List<Post> getAll() {
    try {
        return webClient
                .get()
                .uri("/posts")
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToFlux(Post.class)
                .collectList()
                .block();
    }  catch (ReadTimeoutException ex) {
        log.error("A ReadTimeoutException occurred: {}", ex.getLocalizedMessage());
        throw new ApiReadTimeOutException(ex.getLocalizedMessage(), ex);
    } catch (WebClientRequestException ex) {
        log.error("A WebClientRequestException occurred: {}", ex.getLocalizedMessage());
        throw new ApiException(ex.getLocalizedMessage(), ex);
    }
}
```

And my code to simulate a timeout. The WebClient for my stub has a timeout of 5 seconds.

```
stubFor(get(urlEqualTo("/posts")).willReturn(
        aResponse()
                .withStatus(HttpStatus.OK.value())
                .withBodyFile("all-posts.json")
                .withHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                .withFixedDelay(10000)
));
```

From this a `ReadTimeoutException` is thrown, however, it's not being captured in the first catch block. I want it to be captured there. It's being captured in the second catch block.

What do I need to do to make `ReadTimeoutException` be captured in the first catch block?

Comment: If it is caught in the second catch block, then the exception is **not** a `ReadTimeoutException` (or a `ReadTimeOutException` with a different fully-qualified name than the one you imported, or one that is **wrapped** in a `WebClientRequestException`. Maybe consider logging the entire stacktrace to inspect the actual types instead of just the message text.

Comment: have you tried `.onError...()` callbacks on your chain? For example, `.onErrorMap(ReadTimeoutException.class, e -> new RuntimeException("your custom exception here"))`